# Python 3 script uses too much memory

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

As homework for IT lessons I need to write a script which will check for the highest power of 4 which is in modified input number, but I can use only 8MB of RAM. I used for this logarithmic function, so my code looks like this:

```py
from math import log, floor

n = int(input())
numbers = []

for i in range (0, n):
    numbers.append(floor(int(input()) / 10))

for i in numbers:
    print(4 ** floor(log(i, 4)))
```

But I checked this script on my PC and it uses more than 8MB!

```
Partition of a set of 74690 objects. Total size = 8423721 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  23305  31  2100404  25   2100404  25 str
     1  19322  26  1450248  17   3550652  42 tuple
     2   5017   7   724648   9   4275300  51 types.CodeType
     3   9953  13   716915   9   4992215  59 bytes
     4    742   1   632536   8   5624751  67 type
     5   4618   6   628048   7   6252799  74 function
     6    742   1   405720   5   6658519  79 dict of type
     7    187   0   323112   4   6981631  83 dict of module
     8    612   1   278720   3   7260351  86 dict (no owner)
     9     63   0   107296   1   7367647  87 set
<197 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

On my phone, however, this script uses only 2.5MB:

```
Partition of a set of 35586 objects. Total size = 2435735 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0   9831  28   649462  27    649462  27 str
     1   9014  25   365572  15   1015034  42 tuple
     2   4669  13   261232  11   1276266  52 bytes
     3   2357   7   198684   8   1474950  61 types.CodeType
     4    436   1   166276   7   1641226  67 type
     5   2156   6   155232   6   1796458  74 function
     6    436   1   130836   5   1927294  79 dict of type
     7     93   0    87384   4   2014678  83 dict of module
     8    237   1    62280   3   2076958  85 dict (no owner)     9   1091   3    48004   2   2124962  87 types.WrapperDescriptorType
<115 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

I tried changing list to tuple, but it didn't make any difference.

Is there any possibility to decrease/limit RAM usage?

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: A natural number from 1 to 1000, but that much RAM is used before inputting